# Is it possible to find $D$, given $Α=DBD^{-1}$

Tags: linear-algebra

I have a problem of the form

$A = DBD^{-1}$

where $D$ is a diagonal matrix with nonzero, positive elements, and $A$ and $B$ are both square and known. Is it possible to find $D$, and if not, is there a way to constrain the problem further in order to obtain a solution?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Rewrite it as $AD-DB=0$. You now have a linear system of equations on the entries of $D$.

Comment: No. If such $D$ existed, then $A$ and $B$ would have the same eigenvalues (with the same multiplicities)

Comment: Letting D and putting values of A and B  . Then you can compare both sides .

Comment: Yes if you already know what $A$ and $B$ are. Not in general, though.

Comment: Since I know what A and B are, is there an identity I can use to solve this?

Answer (score 2):

Even in the best of cases you can determine $D$ only up to an overall constant factor because
$$ DBD^{-1} = (cD)B(cD)^{-1} $$
In some cases you can't even do that -- most dramatically if $B$ is diagonal, in which case $A=B$ and $D$ can be any nonsingular diagonal matrix whatsoever.

In general, follow Omnomnomnom's advice and rearrange to $AD=DB$. Each non-zero off-diagonal element of $B$ now gives rise to a linear equation connecting the logarithms of two the elements of $D$:
$$ a_{ij}d_j = d_ib_{ij} \implies \log d_i - \log d_j = \log\frac{a_{ij}}{b_{ij}} $$
If you have enough nonzero elements that they correspond to a *connected* graph between the $d_i$s, you can arbitrarily set $d_1=1$ and work out what the other $d_i$s must be by working your way through the graph.

The more connected components the graph has, the more freedom will you have to choose the $d_i$s independently of each other. The extreme case, as noted above, is when $B$ is diagonal, in which case the graph consists of isolated vertices and no edges.

Comment: Thank you so much! I will work through this.